# Hide WebBrowser control

Tags: winapi, iwebbrowser2

I have a Win32 application which converts HTML into an image without displaying the control. (I dont have much experience to use ActiveX in a Win32 application).

I followed this MSDN article to create the control and call `Navigate()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa451946.aspx

When I need to convert the image, I call `IViewObjec::Draw()`. The problem is the control is always visible even if I call the following function:

```
browser->put_Visible(VARIANT_FALSE); // browser is IWebBrowser2
```

When I stepped into the code I found out that when I call

```
mOleObject->DoVerb(OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE, NULL, mControlSite, 0, NULL, NULL)
```

the control becomes visible immediately. But from what I can see from MSDN is that `OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE` means

> Activates an object in place without displaying tools, such as menus and toolbars, that end users need to change the behavior or appearance of the object. Single-clicking such an object causes it to negotiate the display of its user-interface tools with its container. If the container refuses, the object remains active but without its tools displayed.

I am a bit confused, I only want to hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution.

I just make normal window and put the html control into the windown and hide it, which solves all the problems that I mentioned above.

In the ControlSite I implemented IOleWindow::GetWindow() to put control like following code (mWindow is just my Basic window class), just return this normal window's handle.

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetWindow(/* [out] */ HWND __RPC_FAR* theWindow)
{   
    *theWindow = mWindow.GetHandle();
    return S_OK;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `DoVerb()` for the instance of `IOleObject` type (in your case, `mOleObject`) and pass `OLEIVERB_HIDE` as verb.

Update:

The `IHTMLElementRender` interface would be better to solve the problem (see [Capture an HTML document as an image](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6601/Capture-an-HTML-document-as-an-image)).

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have tried OLEIVERB_HIDE, there will be no window shown. But I dont get pixels by calling IViewObjec::Draw()

Comment: Yes, I tried that code from beginning, it has other problems. 1. It uses MFC. 2. The result does not show any flash or <canvas/> and 3. microsoft said that the function is deprecated.  4. I tried to use ATL template class to show put IWebBrowser control, and when I create the window, my own main window suddenly become inactive.